# Perl: Unwrapping list inside-out doesn't work?

Tags: perl

```
$all="{this, {is, some, {deeply, nested}, text}, for, you}";
while ($all=~s/{([^{}]*?)}/f($1)/seg) {}
sub f {return \{split(",",$_[0])};}
print @{$all};
```

I expect $all to be a listref whose list contains:

```
{this, [reference to array], for, you}
```

Instead, @{$all} is empty.

I'm sure this is something basic, but what am I doing wrong?

Note: I intentionally "golfed" the code to post here (ie, minimal code that shows the problem). A more extensive version is at: https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/playground.pl

EDIT: Thanks to everyone who answered! Notes:

- The real f() has side effects, updates dbs, etc, so I really do have to call it. It doesn't just 
  change a list into something else. My bad for not mentioning this.
- I was exporting from Mathematica so "{a,b,c}" is a list, not a 
  hash. Again, mea culpa for not mentioning this.
- I know the "normal" way to do this is recursive: process each 
  element, and if an element is a list, call f() on the list itself. I 
  was trying to do "unfold" the recursion to avoid splitting nested 
  "{". If you work inside out, you never have to count "{" when 
  parsing.
- An interesting other application would be a one-line XML parser (almost).
- Giving geekosaur the checkmark for pointing out what was wrong and 
  why my approach is probably wrong.
- I think I'll try the Parser approach or even jrey's s/{/[ approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have `$all` simultaneously be a string you're iteratively matching on *and* an arrayref collecting the result of the iteration.  `$all` will end up being something like the string `"thisARRAY(0xdeadbeef)foryou"`, and `@$all` will use it as a package symbol name, which almost certainly isn't defined, so it will autovivify as an empty list.

Additionally, `{}` is already a (`HASH` instead of `ARRAY`) reference, so you're returning a `SCALAR` ref to a `HASH` ref instead of an `ARRAY` ref as you apparently expect.  And `{}` are special in regexes (`foo{1,3}` means 1 to 3 repetitions of `foo`), so you should escape them.

The correct way to do it is to collect into a result list, something like

```
my @res;
while ($all =~ /\G\{([^{}]*?)\}/sg) {
    push @res, f($1);
}
```

`use warnings` and `use strict` would have told you something was wrong, if not precisely what.  Use them.  Always.

Answer (score 2):

Use a parser.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;
use Parse::RecDescent;

my $all = "{this, {is, some, {deeply, nested}, text}, for, you}";

my $p = Parse::RecDescent->new(q[
  list: '{' <commit> listitem(s /,/) '}' { $return = $item[3] }
      | <error?>
  listitem: word | list
  word: /\w+/
]);

my $l = $p->list($all);
die "$0: bad list\n" unless defined $l;

$Data::Dumper::Indent = $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
print Dumper $l;
```

Output:

```
[
  'this',
  [
    'is',
    'some',
    [
      'deeply',
      'nested'
    ],
    'text'
  ],
  'for',
  'you'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your text format is easy to transform into Perl, after that you may eval it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
my $all = "{this, {is, some, {deeply, nested}, text}, for, you}";

$all =~ s/\s*,\s*/','/g;
$all =~ s/'?\{/['/g;
$all =~ s/\}'?/']/g;
my $result = eval $all;

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $result;
```